# Here API Maps set marker

Tags: javascript, maps, here-api

I'm using HERE API Maps. How can i add custom icons for map with clustering and bounds? I know how i can do this if i have single marker. But how add icons if i have a group of markers? 
I think it should be somewhere here...

```js
// Set Map Bounds
function setMapBounds(map) {
  let svgMarkup = '<svg></svg>';
  let svgMarkup2 = '<svg width="24" height="24" ' +
  'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
  '<rect stroke="white" fill="#1b468d" x="1" y="1" width="22" ' +
  'height="22" /><text x="12" y="18" font-size="12pt" ' +
  'font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" text-anchor="middle" ' +
  'fill="white">H</text></svg>';
  let icon = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup);
  let icon2 = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup2);
  let mapBounds = [];
  let urlMapBounds = '/api/catalog/catalog/map/info';

  getDataAjax(urlMapBounds, toRequestJson).done((response) => {
    totalCount = response.count;
    numOfPages = Math.ceil(totalCount / PORTION);

    // Set Top-left and Bottom-right invisible bound markers 
    mapBounds.push(new H.map.Marker({lat: response.leftUp.lat, lng: response.leftUp.lng}, {icon: icon}));
    mapBounds.push(new H.map.Marker({lat: response.rightBottom.lat, lng: response.rightBottom.lng}, {icon: icon}));

    // Add bound markers to the group
    let group = new H.map.Group();
        group.addObjects(mapBounds);
        map.addObject(group);
  
    // Get geo bounding box for the group and set it to the map
    map.setViewBounds(group.getBounds());

    // Run function of getting data for clustering
    getDataForClustering(map)
  });
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what do you actually need. You asked how to add custom icon, but you already have 2 Markers with custom svg Icon. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I think the markers weren't displayed on the map may be? @Tomas

Comment: @gopal No. Pony is asking how to add icon for group of markers. But he actually did it correctly in the code. The reason why nothing is displayed is, that he uses `icon` for both markers which has empty svg markup. IF you create marker with second icon (`icon2`), it is displayed properly.

Answer (score 1):

Check this example from [developer](https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/maps-js/markers/map-with-svg-graphic-markers) portal where you can group multiple markers in a function like below.

```
var cubsIcon = new H.map.Icon(
    svgMarkup.replace('${FILL}', 'white').replace('${STROKE}', 'orange')),
    cubsMarker = new H.map.Marker({lat: 41.9483, lng: -87.6555 },
      {icon: cubsIcon});

  map.addObject(cubsMarker);
```